# Kendo Tree, starting with a number of nodes then dynamically loading the rest

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I am starting to work with a Kendo TreeView, I have an implementation which loads a number of treenodes at startup from a Asp MVC project

I'm not sure how to then dynamically load the other nodes, the documentation is pretty sparse in this area

I'm including the source below as I think it will be useful to others if nothing else. This code works for loading 'n' tree nodes

```
<script>    
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource( {
        transport: {
            read: function ( options )
            {
                debugger;
                $.ajax( {
                    url: "/EmployeePicker/EmployeePicker/GetTreeRoot",
                    async: false, //ensure the response is received before exiting the content function
                    success: function ( r )
                    {                       
                        options.success( r );
                    }
                } );
            }                           
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                children: "Children"
            }
        }
    } );

    dataSource.read();

    var rootItems = dataSource.data();

    rootItems[0].load(); // does not initiate AJAX request

    $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        dataTextField: "Name"
    } );


</script>
```

and the MVC side.

```
public JsonResult GetTreeRoot()
{
    TreeNode root = new TreeNode("1",  "Root", true);           
    TreeNode childA = new TreeNode("1.1", "ChildA", true);
    TreeNode childA1 = new TreeNode("1.1.1", "ChildA1", false);

    // this one has a child but we're not initialising it
    TreeNode childB = new TreeNode("1.2", "ChildB", true);

    root.Children.Add(childA);
    root.Children.Add(childB);
    childA.Children.Add(childA1);

    List<TreeNode> list = new List<TreeNode>();
    list.Add(root);

    return Json(list, System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is perfectly possible with Kendo, and there is a working demo here on SO at [Lazy load in Kendo UI treeview with caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20470822/lazy-load-in-kendo-ui-treeview-with-caching/20563225#20563225).

They key is in defining the `transport.read` function:

```
var homogeneous = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
  transport: {
    read: function (options) {
      var id = options.data.id;
      var data = get(localData, id);
      if (data) {
        options.success(data);
      } else {
        // get remote children based on parent 'id'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Check the demo linked above for the full example.

Answer (score 0):

This will need to go via Ajax but it adds a node where required. The key thing here is that the server has indicated that the node has children but the treeview can see they haven't loaded yet

```
$( "#treeview" ).kendoTreeView( {
            dataSource: dataSource,
            dataTextField: "Name",
            expand: expandNode
        } );


    function expandNode(e)
    {       
        var node = $( "#treeview" ).data( "kendoTreeView" ).dataItem( e.node )

        if ( node.Children.length > 0 )
            return;

        var treeview = $( "#treeview" ).data( "kendoTreeView" )

        var newNode = { Name: "NewNode", hasChildren: true, id: "4.1"};

        treeview.append(newNode, $(e.node) );
    }
```

Comment: while this is possible, it duplicates much of the work that the TreeView DataSource binding gives you. keep the data fetching in the DataSource transport, as shown in Dan's answer.

Comment: Also, as I've discovered since, if you want the loading spinner effect (essential for usability) then you need to use the built in mechanisms, e.g. 

transport: {
  read: {
    url: "<my url>" + "?token=" + token + "&",
    dataType: "json"
  }
},